# How to apply curved motion to a transition?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-transitions

Following [this](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-shared-element-transitions-activities-fragments-631996/) tutorial I was able to implement shared element transition between fragments. Now I'd like to sweeten it up by changing the motion path of shared element. More specifically I'd like shared element to travel on a curved a path.

As per documentation, I could add an `ArcMotion` to my transition but - for as much as I understood - with `ArcMotion`. I can't control the direction in which the curve is bending. It moves on circular path but in anticlockwise manner. Right now my `TransitionSet` looks as follows:

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500">
    <changeBounds/>
    <changeTransform/>
    <changeImageTransform/>
    <arcMotion 
        android:minimumHorizontalAngle="90" 
        android:minimumVerticalAngle="90" 
        android:maximumAngle="15"/>
</transitionSet>
```

What can I replace the `ArcMotion` with to have a bit more control over the curve? Is there any other way I can achieve this than arc motion?

Comment: You can always make your own animation with your own custom Interpolator: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html or if you want to keep the motion (changing bounds with a path) you can implement your own PathMotion and base it off the code in ArcMotion, http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/transition/ArcMotion.java

Comment: @JohanShogun How do I add an animation to `TransitionSet`? I have found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/guohai/2293628) with `Animation` object that contains arc translation but I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: For a TransitionSet you'll have to implement your own PathMotion :). Easiest thing to do is basing it of the existing ArcMotion (see previous comment) and changing the getPath method to fit your needs. Keep in mind  you use it like this "<pathMotion class="my.app.transition.MyPathMotion"/>"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to achieve it I have to create `PathMotion`. For example like this:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class TransitionArcMotion extends PathMotion {
    private static int DEFAULT_RADIUS = 500;
    private float curveRadius;

    public TransitionArcMotion() {

    }

    public TransitionArcMotion(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TransitionArcMotion);
        curveRadius = a.getInteger(R.styleable.TransitionArcMotion_arcRadius, DEFAULT_RADIUS);
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public Path getPath(float startX, float startY, float endX, float endY) {
        Path arcPath = new Path();

        float midX = startX + ((endX - startX) / 2);
        float midY = startY + ((endY - startY) / 2);
        float xDiff = midX - startX;
        float yDiff = midY - startY;

        double angle = (Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * (180 / Math.PI)) - 90;
        double angleRadians = Math.toRadians(angle);

        float pointX = (float) (midX + curveRadius * Math.cos(angleRadians));
        float pointY = (float) (midY + curveRadius * Math.sin(angleRadians));

        arcPath.moveTo(startX, startY);
        arcPath.cubicTo(startX,startY,pointX, pointY, endX, endY);
        return arcPath;
    }
}
```

Then I have to pass my path motion to `TransitionSet` resource:

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:duration="250">
<changeBounds>
    <pathMotion class="com.sony.songpal.app.view.motion.TransitionArcMotion" app:arcRadius="250"/>
</changeBounds>
<changeTransform/>
<changeImageTransform/>
```

Comment: hi, can you post the TransitionArcMotion styleable file?

Comment: Great !!! This getPath() method provide path to arc at right side. Can you please provide Path for left side arc?

Answer (score 2):

just a completion for the answer of Booyaches.
To declare your `Styleable` you need to go under your

> res/values/style

and inside your style file you need to add:

```
<resources>
  // others styles .....

  <declare-styleable name="TransitionArcMotion">
    <attr name="arcRadius" format="integer" />
  </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

**or another option** you can create a new file called `attrs.xml` inside `res/values` folder, leaving you the next path:

> res/values/attrs

and inside this file add the same code:

```
<resources>
  // others styles .....

  <declare-styleable name="TransitionArcMotion">
    <attr name="arcRadius" format="integer" />
  </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```